# Dropdown menu from list in Flask application not passing the value correctly?

Tags: python, flask

I have provided the code of how I'm getting to the values of the list for context.

application.py

```
sheet_url = "google sheet url"
clientSheetURL = sheet_url.replace("/edit#gid=", "/export?format=csv&gid=")
clientData = pd.read_csv(clientSheetURL)
clientList = clientData['Name'].values.tolist()

@ app.route("/")
def index2():
    print("CL" + str(clientList))
    return render_template("index.html", clients=clientList)

@ app.route("/code", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def code():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.form.get("docxfile")
        linkText = request.form["toreplace"]
        link = request.form["link"]
        client = request.form.get("client")
```

Index.html

```
<select id="client" name="client">

            {%for client in clients%}

            <option value="{{client}}">{{client}}</option>

            {%endfor%}
            <option value="DDC">DDC</option>
            <option value="DI">DealerInspire</option>
            </select>
```

I can print out the values DDC and DI when I select them, and the options populate correctly in the dropdown for the client options on the website, but the value is not being passed back into the flask application and prints out blank.

Answer (score 0):

All, I discovered that it was outputting the list as a list of objects... I believe at least... I solved it by adding the following line under the creation of "clientList" and forcing them all to be strings:

```
for cli in clientList:
    cli = str(cli)
```

Unsure as to why it was still outputting correctly in the dropdown and not the value, but this will do for now: